# HTML Layout - nested rows and columns

Tags: html, layout, html-table

[image]

According to the above image, using my understanding, I have this code

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td style="width:30%";>
           <tr>A</tr>
           <tr>
               <td style="width:33%;">B</td>
               <td style="width:33%;">C</td>
               <td rowspan="2" style="width:33%;">D</td>
           </tr>
           <tr><td colspan="2">E</td></tr>
       </td>
       <td style="width:70%";>
           <tr>Lorem Ipsum ... <img src="pic.jpg"></tr>
           <tr><img src="pic.jpg">Lorem Ipsum ... </tr> 
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However when I did not include the 'tr tag' under the 'td tag' 30% or 70%, the layout of the box will be there, but once I add in the 'tr tag' everything just go haywire. Are there any other way to create the layout like in the image attached?

Comment: Something looks wrong with that table. It has an incorrect tag structure, you can use something like this: http://divtable.com/generator/, to generate correct table layouts, see if you can nest the needed tables. Let me know if you need help creating the layout.

Comment: The correct way is to use CSS with normal HTML elements. Have you used a table for any specific reason? Also, you can't put a 'tr' under 'td', that's a row inside a column - the row has to go inside a new table element first.

Answer (score 0):

the basic structure is

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>table layout</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 30%">
                <table style="width: 100%;height: 400px;">
                    <tr><td colspan="3">A</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:33%;">B</td>
                        <td style="width:33%;">C</td>
                        <td rowspan="2" style="width:33%;">D</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2">E</td></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 70%">
                <table style="width: 100%;height: 400px">
                    <tr><td><p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum ... </p><img src="banner-test.jpg" style="width: 200px;float: right"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><img src="banner-test.jpg" style="width: 200px" >Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum ... </td></tr> 
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table> 
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but for the image side, how do i make the texts wrap around both the images to look like the image i posted in the question?